# R blueprints / floorplan

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on trying to represent an office building in R. Later, I'll need to represent multiple floors, but for now I need to start with one floor. There are clusters of cubes all in a regular structure. There are four small cubes for junior staff (4x4), and two larger cubes for a senior engineer and a manager (4x6). Once these are mapped out, I need to be able to show if they are occupied or free for new hires -- by color (like red for occupied, green for available). These are all laid out the same way, with the big ones on one end. For example,

```
+----+--+--+
| S  |J1|J2|
+----+--+--+
<-hallway-->
+----+--+--+
| M  |J3|J4|
+----+--+--+
```

I first thought I could use ggplot and just scatter plot everybody out, but I can't figure out how to capture the different size cubes with geom_point. I spent some time looking at maps, but it seems like I can't really take advantage of the regular structure of my floorplan -- maybe that really is the way to go and I take advantage of my regular structure in building out a map? Does R have a concept I should Google for this kind of structure?

In the end, I'll get a long data file, with the type of cubicle, the x and y coordinates of the cluster, and a "R" or "G" (4 columns).

Comment: Maybe you can use `geom_tile` from `ggpolot2`? http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html

Comment: I saw that, but it looks like all the tiles need to be the same size?

Comment: Simplest solution would be to use a background image with floor plan and a `geom_point`/`geom_rect`, would it be sufficient?

Comment: `mosaicplot(matrix(c(3,1,2,3,1,2), 3), off = c(5,20))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also write a low-level graphic function; it's sometimes easier to tune than removing more and more components from a complex plot,

[image]

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

floorGrob <- function(S = c(TRUE, FALSE), J = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), 
                      draw=TRUE, newpage=is.null(vp), vp=NULL){
  m <- rbind(c(1,3,4), # S1 J1 J2
             c(7,7,7), # hall
             c(2,5,6)) # S2 J3 J4
  fills <- c(c("#FBB4AE","#CCEBC5")[c(S, J)+1],  "grey90")
  cellGrob <- function(f) rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=f, col="white", lwd=2))
  grobs <- mapply(cellGrob, f=fills, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  g <- arrangeGrob(grobs = grobs, layout_matrix = m, vp = vp, as.table = FALSE,
              heights = unit(c(4/14, 1/14, 4/14), "null"),
              widths = unit(c(6/14, 4/14, 4/14), "null"), respect=TRUE)

  if(draw) {
    if(newpage) grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(g)
  }
  invisible(g)
}

floorGrob()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5)
df$color <- factor(sample(c("green", "red"), 36, replace = T))
head(df)
#   x y color
# 1 0 0 green
# 2 1 0 green
# 3 2 0 green
# 4 3 0   red
# 5 4 0 green
# 6 5 0   red

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = color)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Is it open?",
                    values = c("lightgreen", "#FF3333"),
                    labels = c("open", "not open"))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I can't figure out how to tell geom_tile() that some X (or Y) tiles are bigger than others. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: You can provide parameters `geom_tile(aes(width = w, height = h))` for each tile.